# Why does binding not work between View and ViewModel in Playgrounds?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `TextField` which is user editable, but may also be updated by changes to a `ViewModel`.

There seems to be some arcane magic determining when my `TextField` updates itsself, however.

Here's a playground:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var text: String = "0"

    private var cancellables: [AnyCancellable] = []

    init() {
        // output what the value of `text` is, whenever it changes
        let c = $text.print().sink { _ in }
        cancellables.append(c)
    }

    func fetch() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.text += "3"
        }
    }

    deinit { print("deinit") }
}

struct V: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    init() {
        viewModel.text += "1"
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField("TextField", text: $viewModel.text)
            .onAppear { self.viewModel.text += "2" }
            .onAppear { self.viewModel.fetch() }
    }
}

var v: V? = V()

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
    v = nil
}
```

I can see from the `print()` in `ViewModel.init()` that `ViewModel.text` is updated as expected. Final value: `0123`.

**What I don't understand: why does the `TextField` value stop updating when it reaches `012`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works even in Playground.

To see the resulting View in Playground, you need to tell the Playground to show it.

```
import PlaygroundSupport
```

and

```
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(v)
```

will do the trick. Finally I also change

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("TextField", text: $viewModel.text).font(.largeTitle)
            .onAppear {
                self.viewModel.text += "2"
                self.viewModel.fetch()
        }
            Text(viewModel.text).font(.largeTitle).frame(width: 200)
        }
    }
```

so all changes will be directly visible.

So or so, testing in real environment is necessary.

[image]

Comment: I'm downvoting this because you've changed my code in order to make it work without mentioning what you've done. After squinting at the gif, I can see that the key to fixing this was the addition of `PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(v)`. If you fancy editing your answer to illustrate this, I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

It is Playground-specific behaviour, because it, seems, recreate view on every update (even from view model), so `fetch` just not received. Put this code in project and test in Live Preview or Simulator - all works well.

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right. In transferring the code from my project to a standalone playground, I fixed the original issue and introduced a whole new one :/